# How to connect Buttons to Dictionaries in Tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, user-interface, tkinter

I want to make a bunch of buttons when I run this code. Then, if you click on the button, I want to show the content that corresponds to that button in my dictionary.

I've created the dictionary and it is populated, but I just don't know how to tell the button to look up that word in the dictionary. This is what I have so far, and I just want to know how to make it so you click the button and the corresponding text is printed to the terminal. As of now, this just results in the creation of the buttons in a grid according to the list of words (which is a 2d array). My dictionary is called my_dict and show_content should print the content in the dictionary with the value at wordList[x][y].

````py
def url_entry():
    for y in range(len(wordList)):
        WebScrape.yolo(e1.get(), wordList[y], countList[y],my_dict)
        for x in range(len(wordList[y])):
            if countList[y][x] > 0:
                text_to_use = '{0} \n({1})'.format(wordList[y][x], countList[y][x])
                tk.Button(text=text_to_use, relief=tk.RIDGE, width=15, command=show_content).grid(row=5 + x,column=y)
def show_content():
    print(my_dict[x])```
````

Answer (score 1):

here is a little example:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.dict_ = {"button_1": "value of button 1", "button_2": "value of button 2", "button_3": "value of button 3"}


        self.button_1 = Button(master, text="button_1", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick("button_1"))
        self.button_1.pack()

        self.button_2 = Button(master, text="button_2", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick("button_2"))
        self.button_2.pack()

        self.button_3 = Button(master, text="button_3", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick("button_3"))
        self.button_3.pack()

    def OnButtonClick(self, btn):
        print(self.dict_[btn])

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

output:

button_2 clicked

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me, as I am dynamically creating the buttons. I will not know how many buttons I will have, so I cannot instantiate button_1, etc. Do you know how I will do this but dynamically?

Comment: I fixed it by adding an argument before my lambda function. so it looked like ```tk.Button(text=text_to_use, relief=tk.RIDGE, width=15, command=lambda new_cord=(x,y): show_content(new_cord)).grid(row=5 + x,column=y)```